# Is it safe to use an impure reducer in Array.prototype.reduce?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I was wondering if it's safe to use an impure reducer in `array.prototype.reduce` in javascript.

Example:

Let's say a I have following array:

```
[{ id: 0, value: 6 }, { id: 1, value: 25 }]
```

If I wanted to convert this to a map where the ID became the key and the value the value.

I have two options here: with a pure reducer and an impure one.

```
// pure option
const data = [{ id: 0, value: 6 }, { id: 1, value: 25 }];
const object = data.reduce((accum, { id, value }) =>
  Object.assign({}, accum, { [id]: value }), 
  {}
);
const map = new Map(Object.entries(object));
// impure option
const data = [{ id: 0, value: 6 }, { id: 1, value: 25 }];
const map = data.reduce(
  (accum, { id, value }) => accum.set(id, value),
  new Map()
);
```

While the impure option is alot faster and has less boilerplate code, I am not sure if it's safe to or if it can give race conditions.

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded; in synchronous code, there won't be race conditions.

Comment: Side note: Have you run your examples? 1st option seems to not work as `assign`'s target object is lost

Comment: Third option: `new Map(data.map(({ id, value }) => ([id, value])))`

Comment: Not using local effects would mean to restrict yourself without getting the guarantees  pure functional languages provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-thinking this.

That's ok, a lot of us (myself included) wind up there. But ask yourself this question: from the perspective of the entity that is using your Map, can you tell the difference? Answer: no. In fact, a sufficiently smart compiler would turn the former into the latter. While I generally try to avoid being a human compiler while writing code, in this case the impure version is both shorter *and* clearer *and* faster.

*Local* state in Javascript is *fine*.

This is not to say that *anything* goes, I wouldn't mutate an external datastructure inside a reducer (or in any other function for that matter) but mutating one that doesn't "leak" outside the call to reduce and is instantiated solely for the purpose of being constructed that way is fine.